# Why the last element in array using negative index slice is not showing?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, slice

I want to slice an array from the last element to the first element using a for loop to reduce the array, this is my code but for an reason the last element is not showing. Ignore the name of the function.

```
    def find_even_index(arr):
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            print(arr[-(len(arr)):-i])

    find_even_index([1,2,3,4,3,2,1]),3)
```

Result:

```
    []
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2]
    [1]
```

Expect result:

```
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2]
    [1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working:

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[:len(arr) - i])

find_even_index([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])

#prints:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[1]
```

When you had

```
arr[:-i]
```

i started at 1, so you told it, in essence, to do

```
arr[0:-0]
# which is
arr[0:0]
```

Which is what caused it to print nothing. instead, start at the length of the array and incrementally subtract 1.

Answer (score 3):

The farthest right you can specify with a negative index is `-1`, which refers to the final item in a sequence. However, slice semantics are that the index following the `:` is excluded from the slice.

Therefore, there is no way, using a negative index to the right of the `:`, to include the final item in a list.

You could "fix" this in your function by replacing `-i` with `-i if i else len(arr)`:

```py
def find_even_index(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[-(len(arr)):-i if i else len(arr)])

find_even_index([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[1]
```